# Using the processing.org trig functions correctly

Tags: processing

This is really driving me nuts and I know I'm being silly somehow. Why isn't this line 45 degrees?

```
    size(800, 600);
    background (30);  
    stroke(255);

    float r = 100;
    float a= 20+   r * cos(radians(QUARTER_PI))   ;
    float b= 20+   r * sin(radians(QUARTER_PI))   ;
    line(20,20,a,b);
```

I've simplified this code from a larger project and if I do a lot of iterations the circle appears. What have I done to make the angle scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start off by debugging the code. The line is not 45 degrees because of the values being passed to `line()`. By printing the values for `a` and `b`, it's obvious the line is being drawn from coordinate (20,20) to roughly (119, 21). So you are telling the program to draw a straight line.

```
print(a + "\n");  // returns 119.99
print(b);         // returns 21.37
```

If you want to draw a circle, why not use the [`ellipse()`](http://processing.org/reference/ellipse_.html) function?

---

**EDIT:**

The problem with your code is that you are passing into the `radians()` function the value `QUARTER_PI`, which is already in radians. Therefore, your problem could be solved in either of these ways:

```
// Pass in an amount of radians directly.
float r = 100;
float a = 20 + r * cos(QUARTER_PI);
float b = 20 + r * sin(QUARTER_PI);
line(20,20,a,b);
```

or

```
// Pass in degrees converted to radians.
float r = 100;
float a = 20 + r * cos(radians(45));
float b = 20 + r * sin(radians(45));
line(20,20,a,b);
```

Comment: It should be 45 degrees because sin(pi/4) and cos(pi/4) are equal to the same thing - but they arent being computed as equal. Can you see why this is?

Comment: This is because radians(PI/4) does not equal PI/4, however radians(45) does equal PI/4. The `radians()` function must get a value of degrees as its argument. Passing a value in radians to the `radians()` function is not a meaningful operation.

Comment: Ah I see thankyou -
I had actually added that function after I had seen these problems but obviously it only made matters worse. I'll try and see if I've mixed up any more units with my larger project, if not ill post the code